# Mock private static final String using Mockito

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I am having a difficulty time mocking a private static final String field in a class. Here is my java sample code:

```
public class Fruit {
private static final String FRUIT = "apple";

public void getFruit() {
    System.out.println("I like " + FRUIT);
}
```

}

And I used Mockito to mock the FRUIT variable so that I can change the value of FRUIT from "apple" to "mango". For that here is my test:

```
public class FruitTest {
@Test
public void testFruit() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, Exception {
    setFinalStatic(Fruit.class.getDeclaredField("FRUIT"), "mango");
    Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
    fruit.getFruit();
}

static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(null, newValue);
}
```

}

I was expecting when I do `System.out.println("I like " + FRUIT);`
 it will print mango, but still it is printing apple. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this ONLY USING MOCKITO and not PowerMock etc.

Comment: The behavior of the `Fruit` class will be to always return `apple`.  Therefore, I don't think you should be looking to change this.  If you want the possibility of returning a variable type of fruit, then don't make the field `static final`, and use `when()` to mock the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the value of a constant is not a good practice. What it is more,I think is not possible. However if you want to change the value of a field, remove the modifier `final.

Answer (score 0):

Compile-time constants can be inlined by javac for optimization. If you change your Fruit class something like:

public static class Fruit {
        public static final String FRUIT = getFruit();

```
    public static String getFruit() {
        return "apple";
    }



}
```

It will show the result mango with 
setFinalStatic(Fruit.class.getField("FRUIT"), "mango");
System.out.println(Fruit.FRUIT);

Answer (score 0):

I looked into mocking some static fields recently and I don't think you can do what you are trying to without the aid of powermock. I am also not sure why you would want to. A private static final field is a constant, and there should not be a real reason why you would want a constant to change. Any test trying to do so is trying to test the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

The word **final** describes precisely that you are not supposed to change that value once that String is created. This is the way you get constants in Java. Your getFruit method will always return "apple". Mockito won't help you with that. If you are testing this method you need to test that it always returns "apple". And in your case it doesn't matter wether the method is static or not since what you are returning is a constant value. Using reflection is not a good idea, not just because it is a really bad coding practice, but also because you don't have a way to properly manage changes in the future. It's such an invasive code that requires tremendous amounts of maintenance and it always generates several number of lines just to get that method to change during runtime so that it "can be tested". All in all real life cases don't need reflection in unit tests unless of course there is a strong reason for it or just that the architecture needs improvement. Reflection is more of an academic thing or if you are building your own injection system, a mocking tool or anything that requires that kind of coding.